# Calling python server function from C++ using XML-RPC

Tags: c++, python

I need to call my python function from C++ code. A XML-RPC server is running on the python server so do we have some way to call the python server function through C++ code using XML-RPC server call

Comment: How about [let me google that for you](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/xmlrpc-howto-python.html)

Comment: @Shark He wanted to call it from a c++ client. Same still applies though...

Comment: @JosephPla I understand, and - exactly my point ;)

Answer (score 1):

XML RPC is platform independent so it doesn't matter what the server is written in. The following is a link to a small library for formatting and sending XML RPC messages to your server.

Here you go: [XMLRPC For C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/downloading.php)

Or this one: [ulxmlrpcpp](http://ulxmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net)

There are many more implementations for C and C++. A quick google search could have gotten you that answer though ;)